# compare two FEN string to prevent impossible positions in chess

Tags: node.js, chess, chessboard.js, fen

I implemented a chessboard with chessboard.js and when position change the FEN string is sending to my node.js server using socket.io

The question is, How i can prevent illegal moves or how i can find FEN is possible in every move situation?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, sending every move to server via socket and check the move validity in time with chess.js library, the solution i found in mind.

Comment: It makes no sense because it involves network delay. Use a FEN library.

Comment: how can a FEN library compare two sequential fen strings and find validity of new position?